# Error "pod has unbound immediate PersistentVolumeClaim" during statefulset deployment

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-statefulset

I am deploying stolon via statefulset (default from stolon repo). 
I have define in statefulset config

```
volumeClaimTemplates:     
    - metadata:    
        name: data   
      spec:   
        accessModes: ["ReadWriteOnce"]   
        storageClassName: stolon-local-storage  
        resources:
          requests:
            storage: 1Gi
```

and here is my storageClass:

```
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1   
kind: StorageClass   
metadata:   
  name: stolon-local-storage  
provisioner: kubernetes.io/no-provisioner  
volumeBindingMode: WaitForFirstConsumer
```

statefulset was created fine, but pod has error:
**pod has unbound immediate PersistentVolumeClaims**

How can I resolve it?

Comment: Hi, can your describe your pv `kubectl describe pv $PV_NAME` ?

Comment: Can You add information from `kubectl get sc -A`? I think your default namespace is not stolon-local-storage, [there](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/change-default-storage-class/) You can read about this. Basically You need to use this command `kubectl patch storageclass stolon-local-storage -p '{"metadata": {"annotations":{"storageclass.kubernetes.io/is-default-class":"true"}}}'` to make your new created storageClass default. Let me know if that helped

Comment: @SureshVishnoi - thanks for idea (and formating my question - from mobile it's crazy). I didn't create folders on the nodes.

Comment: @jt97 - yes, it helped. I needed to add isDefaultClass: true. Thanks!

Comment: @Donets No problem, let me make an answer from it and accept it please.

Answer (score 1):

> pod has unbound immediate PersistentVolumeClaims

In this case pvc could not connect to storageclass because it wasn't make as a [default](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/change-default-storage-class/).

> Depending on the installation method, your Kubernetes cluster may be deployed with an existing StorageClass that is marked as default. This default StorageClass is then used to dynamically provision storage for PersistentVolumeClaims that do not require any specific storage class. See [PersistentVolumeClaim documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/#class-1) for details.

Command which can be used to make your new created storageclass a default one.

```
kubectl patch storageclass <name_of_storageclass> -p '{"metadata": {"annotations":{"storageclass.kubernetes.io/is-default-class":"true"}}}'
```

Then You can use `kubectl get storageclass` and it should look like this

```
NAME                 PROVISIONER               AGE
stolon-local-storage   (default)   kubernetes.io/gce-pd      1d
```

Comment: Hi, why you have to make it default storage class when you are already passing the storage class name? This doesn't sound to be a solution to the problem to me

Comment: I am running kubernetes with docker-desktop. I have modifed storageclass with: kubectl patch storageclass hostpath -p '{"metadata": {"annotations":{"storageclass.docker.io.hostpath/is-default-class":"true"}}}' still getting same pvc error